# Need help figuring out a specific guitar tone in BiasFX

Tags: guitar, electric-guitar, recording, guitar-effects, tone

Recently got back to guitar now that I have Bias FX and can play without bothering anyone in the house. However, I'm having a hard time figuring out how to create the tones that I want.

Examples of the tone I'm looking for: [1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sywg3fHbYPI) [2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=70nbt5rIrXg) [3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hr6u26mdAnI) [4](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6FDeX4QjbJA)

I know they're not all exactly the same, but they're similar enough.

I don't even know how to describe it well. It's like a slighly distorted, yet very clean and fat tone. Doesn't seem hard to reproduce, but I'm completely new to this, so I really don't know how to do it myself. Would love to get some help on it as I really like how it sounds.

Guitar I'm using is a Dean Cadillac 1980, and I'm connecting it to Bias FX Elite through a mixer using a 1/4 cable.

Answer (score 1):

> slighly distorted, yet very clean and fat tone

Sounds like a general Blues tone. **On any amp or FX circuit**, look for a "gain" or "overdrive" knob/function. If you have a circuit with "pre" and "post" gain options, you can turn the "pre" down and crank the "post" to overdrive the tubes naturally. On a Fender Blues Junior tube combo these are called "master" (pre) and "volume" (post). Basically, play with your various gain stage settings and see if you can get a controlled "overdriven" sound without clipping your signal in the mix.

**On your guitar** and **EQ settings** you'll probably want more bass and midrange than treble. Your Dean Cadillac guitar has humbuckers which will naturally be more bass-midrange heavy than single coil p'ups, so you can probably leave your Tone knob wide open (10?) and simply switch to the neck p'up for this tone. With single coils in neck position I often have my Tone knob set to 7 or 8.
Bridge p'up should give a brighter, crisper sound. On the amp / FX / mixer circuit you're going to want to start flat across the board and slowly dial in your desired sound. I recommend starting with the treble / high EQ option, turning it down until you like it. If that doesn't work well, leave the treble midway and turn the bass and/or mids up. It's all about what sounds good *to you* so you'll need to experiment.

Comment: Just want to add that some guitar Tone knobs have an audio taper, while others have a linear taper. Again, experiment with the settings until it sounds good to you. Record a bit of playing, walk away for a few hours or even better a few days. Come back to it and see if you still like it. Do some A/B comparison. Cognitive Dissonance says that if you listen to the tone too much for too long you'll be unable to listen critically.